# Searching two DataTables at once for one value

Tags: c#

I have two DataTables and I am trying to determine if the tables contain the strings from a list, one string at a time. If the either table contains each string from the list of strings, return true, else false.

Example:

```
public static bool MyMethod()
{
     DataTable table1 = GetMyTable1();
     DataTable table2 = GetMyTable2();

     List<string> requiredList = new List<string>();
     requiredList.Add("foo");
     requiredList.Add("bar");
     requiredList.Add("foobar");

     int counter = 0;

     foreach (DataRow row in table1.Rows)
     {
          if (requiredList.Contains(row["ColumnName"].ToString()))
          {
               counter++;
          }

     }

     foreach (DataRow row in table2.Rows)
     {
           if (requiredList.Contains(row["ColumnName2"].ToString()))
           {
               counter++;
           }
     }

     return (counter == requiredList.Count);
}
```

The list and the datatables will not have duplicates, and I only care about one column. There won't be any duplicates between tables either.

Is there a more efficient way? Is there a way to search through both datatable's columns at the same time instead of having two foreachs?

Comment: The problem with this approach is if you two tables have thousand of rows, you have to retrieve all the rows in memory, I think that the best approach is doing it with raw sql with in clause of better using Entity Framework, It will be further efficient.

Comment: Do both datatables has the same schema?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi the column names are different, and the number of rows can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to loop, there are other options for getting rows from DataTables. You could try a [`.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
foreach(string req in requiredList)
{
    DataRow[] rowsTable1 = table.Select("ColumnName LIKE " + req);
    DataRow[] rowsTable2 = table.Select("ColumnName LIKE " + req);

    counter = counter + rowsTable1.Length + rowsTable2.Length;
}
```

Of course you can replace the `LIKE` in the filter string with whatever operator works best for the string comparison you want.

I can't be certain this will be any quicker, but it at least looks shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best answer, but you could select matching rows from each table and then count those rows like below:

```
        string listItems = String.Join(",", requiredList);

        DataRow[] table1Rows = table1.Select("ColumnName IN (" + listItems + ")");
        DataRow[] table2Rows = table2.Select("ColumnName IN (" + listItems + ")");

        counter = table1Rows.Length + table2Rows.Length;
```

Comment: A good improvement over my answer at the least. I don't know how the performance of Select is over looping through the rows, but this definitely minimizes the amount of time spent looping.

Comment: Didn't work for me. At first, I was getting the error "Invalid Column Name', then I added single quotes inside the parenthesis around listItems, and it got past the error but the number of rows is zero for both datarow arrays.

Comment: These are arrays, so I should have used Length instead of Count()

Answer (score 0):

What you could try to do is to do a `for` loop that iterates until `max(table1.Rows,table2.Rows)`, as the previous answer said.

Also put an `if` statement to take care of being out of bounds